# Proving the dimension of the intersection of 2 subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume that $U$ and $W$ are distinct subspaces $( U  ≠  W )$ of a four-dimensional vector space $V$ and $\dim(U) = \dim(W) = 3$. Prove that $\dim ( U ∩ W ) = 2$.

Answer (score 5):

since U not equal to W, the basis for W must have at least one vector linearly independent from U, so $\dim(U + W)$ is at least 4. but they are subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$, so $\dim (U + W)=4$.

Use the fact that $\dim U +\dim W=\dim(U + W)+ \dim(U\cap W)$, i.e. 
$6=4+\dim(U\cap W)$

Comment: I rewrote the formulae in your post, and  made a correction ($U\cup W$ is not a vector space, hence doesn't have a dimension. It is its span, i.e. $U+W$ which has a dimension.

Comment: How do you prove the fact?